# Allow all types of generic types in a List

Tags: c#, generics

I am having some issues with generics. I have a base-class called Animation, from which different type of animations derive from (e.g double, vector etc etc), and to handle all the animations I use a static class to administrate all the animations basically.

```
public class Animation<T>
{

    public virtual Action<T> UpdateAction { get; set; }
    public EasingFunctionBase EasingFunction { get; set; }

    private TimeSpan _Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }


    public T currentValue { get; internal set; }


    internal TimeSpan CurrentTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
    internal double Percentage = 0;
    internal bool HasFinished = false;

    internal virtual void Update()
    {
        UpdateAction?.Invoke(CurrentValue);
    }


    public virtual void BeginAnimation()
    {
        if (Duration.TotalMilliseconds <= 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You need a duration greater than 0 seconds.");

        AnimationFactory.BeginAnimation(this);
    }
}

DoubleAnimation : Animation<double>
{
    *do some calculations and set currentValue*
}

public static class AnimationFactory
{

    private static List<Animation> _CurrentAnimations = new List<Animation>();

    public static void BeginAnimation<T>(Animation<T> animation)
    {
        // Here is where I'm getting the error. I want this list to be able to contain all types of Animation<T>.
        _CurrentAnimations.Add(animation);

        _isEnabled = true;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < _CurrentAnimations.Count; i++)
        {
            _CurrentAnimations[i].update();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am getting an error where I want to add the newly created and to-be-run-animation into the list. How can I make this list accept **all kinds** of `Animation<T>`? Or am I going about this wrong? I added the generic type in order to remove casting (if animating structs), but maybe there's a smarter solution.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `Animation` class?

Comment: @dotnetom Just did!

Comment: Do you have a class `Animation`, not `Animation<T>`?

Comment: @dotnetom no I do not have a base class Animation, only Animation<T>. Sorry, made a typo(!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make this list accept all kinds of Animation?

Unless `Animation` is a base class of `Animation<T>`, you can't. <s>What is `Animation`? What is its relationship to `Animation<T>`</s>? Based on your additional information, it seems you don't actually have an `Animation` class, yet.

One alternative would be to make the static class generic as well, e.g. `AnimationFactory<T>`. Then the list would be `List<Animation<T>>`. But then you would have a different list for each type parameter `T`, which doesn't seem like what you are looking for.

Based on the information so far, I would say you should make `Animation<T>` inherit `Animation` or some other appropriate base class (using that base class as the type parameter for your `List<T>`). In this particular example, that would require creating the `Animation` base class, since that's not actually something that exists yet.

Barring that, your question might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I.e. you've asked us the wrong question and really should be focused on the broader issue that you're really trying to solve, rather than the nuts and bolts aspect of the list.

Comment: I just made a class Animation, from which Animation<T> derives from. This works wonderfully, and yes, you're probably right - this seems to be an XY problem..